# numpy exception when trying to add 2 vectors

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, vector, numpy-ndarray

In the code snippet below, I am running into some sort of dimension mismatch or matrix singularity issue.

```
def eval(x,m):
    hess = 6*x + m
    return hess

x =np.ones((1, 5))
m =np.ones((1, 5))
D = np.linalg.inv(eval(x, m))
print(D)
```

error:

```
LinAlgError: Last 2 dimensions of the array must be square
```

Comment: Look at `eval(x,m)`. What's its `shape`?  Is that what you expected/wanted?  What shape does `np.linalg.inv` expect?  Reread its docs if necessary.

Comment: With matching `x` and `m` shapes, `eval` returns the same shape (1,5), not a (5,5) that `inv` expects.  Changing `x` to (5,1) will make a square matrix - but singular.

Answer (score 0):

I found my issue. The equation under eval was incorrect. Like hpaulj mentioned, it was returning a singular matrix. With the correct eq it works fine